# How to fix 'The Azure-Ressource is not reachable' for Azure WebApp

Tags: azure, visual-studio, asp.net-core, webdeploy, azure-webapps

Just now i have deployed my WebApp to Azure and want to debug it.
So i opened the Publishing-Profile in VisualStudio and clicked "Hosting/Add Debugger".
As the VisualStudio docs saying, it should connect to the WebApp and starts debugging.
In my case i'm getting "The Azure-Ressource is not reachable".

How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 9):

There was a broken Microsoft-Account in Visual Studio. After reconnecting that account it works as expected.

Comment: This will also fix publish (to  Azure App service) failure issues.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I moved a resource in Azure and needed to update the dependency in VS.

Solution:

1. Publish menu option for project
2. Connected services
3. Edit the dependency for the resource that was moved